# Flutter autofill trigger after correct credential data

Tags: flutter

I used `AutofillGroup` in top of my form.

I used correctly `AutofillHints` in the form.

Data inserted correctly from passwords.

But there is one bug here:

***I want to show promote pop up after server confirm login data***, but promote has been  shown after user press the main button or `Done` on keyboard.

I used `onDisposeAction: null,` but not worked.

When I remove AutofillGroup, promote never shown even with       `TextInput.finishAutofillContext(shouldSave: true);`

Comment: Hi, same issue here. Did you find a solution? Thank you.

Comment: This is a mistake in documantion in flutter and I fixed it.
onDisposeAction: null, => this is not working at all and is not nullable